# Is there any possiblity to center currenlty selected slide in ion-slides?

Tags: html, angular, sass, ionic3

I have a slider with name and avatar of kids. Once user click on specific kid it adds edit button above an avatar. The slider 
What I'm trying to achieve is to center the active slide once user click on it.

Sldier

```html
<ion-slides #slides centeredSlides="true" slidesPerView="3" paginationType="bullets"
            (ionSlideWillChange)="onSlideChanged()">
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let child of children">
                <div *ngIf="child.firstname === selectedChild" class="children__avatar-edit">
                    <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
                </div>
                <span (click)="selectChild(child.firstname)"
                        [ngClass]="child.firstname === selectedChild ? 'children__avatar children__avatar--active' : 'children__avatar'">{{child.avatar}}</span>
                <p class="children__name">{{child.firstname}}</p>
            </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

I've prepared little demo to present it better. Originally kids will be coming from API.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/slides-example

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css to the page scss file.

```
.slider-wrapper {height: 100%;}
```

home.scss

```
page-home {
  .slider-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
   }
  .children {
    &__avatar {
      font-size: 2rem;

      &--active {
        font-size: 3rem;
      }
    }
  }
}
```